# Custom Bootstrapper as Installer Prerequsites winforms VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, bootstrapper, prerequisites

I've a VS2013 setup project which should call some c# code before installation starts.
 First I thought its not possible, but I got a link as 'CustomBootstrapperPackages' from  [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee726596.aspx). I followed all the steps they mentioned and created a sample windowsApp too as in the link and successfully included it as prerequesties.
 But the problem is, it is not opening the form which I created as BootStrapperPackage.
 I'd like to know what is that I missed. Please suggest me if you know some.
Thanks